# Secure CRUD SharePoint rest apis

Tags: sharepoint, crud

Is it possible to secure SharePoint rest APIs?
I have a SharePoint portal that allows users to create accounts an get access to the portal.
The portal uses SharePoint client object model, if any of the users try to access let's say getuserbyid method or retrieving items for lists and changes the ID value, he will be able to retrieve information for other users on the portal.
So it is possible or is their any way to restrict access to the rest APIs outside the portal itself? Because with manipulation using Fiddler or burp suite the request can be replayed with different information or values.

Answer (score 0):

The operations performed by the Client Side Object Model respect the SharePoint site permissions in the SharePoint site you are interacting with.  You need to set/customize the site permissions such that you get the results that you want.